# C Get Date Sometimes Wrong By 1 Day

Tags: c, time

So finally after a lot of time googling I've been able to create a function that gets current date and convert it to string then write to buffer in `C`. But I noticed sometimes the day is off by 1? So for example today is `may 4`, but it may return `may 5`

Here is my code

```
void getCurrentDateTime(char * buffer)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char bufForOut[64] = { 0 };
    strftime(bufForOut, sizeof(bufForOut), "%c", tm);
    strcpy(buffer,bufForOut);
}
```

I call it like

```
char hi[64] = { 0 }
getCurrentDateTime(hi);
print(hi);
```

Comment: maybe the local time zone on your computer is not correct

Comment: @bruceg I live in america, and this script is hosted on a VPS in russia. So could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know how C get current time but in C# it by default returns time from time zone the machine has.

Comment: So.. is it off as seen in Russia or as seen in America? Can't you just print the exact hour and see if it is matching to your expectation?

Comment: pehaps you should set the machine timezone to your timezone (if you need that).

Comment: Unless you've done something to set the time zone (environment variable `TZ`, for example), you'll get the system's default time zone, which is likely to be a Russian time zone since that's where the machine is located.  To track this further, you can (1) print time as well as date, (2) use `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()` to get the information. Between the two, you'll know what the offset between the program's time zone and UTC (GMT) is. If you're using a POSIX-like system, you may be able to `setenv("TZ", "US/Pacific", 1);` (or …) at the start of your program and get the result you want.